# Sitecore Multilist with search returns nothing on the second page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-lucene

I am having problem with a "Multilist with search" field. This is a Sitecore 8 instance. the field is using a query like this to fetch a list from a lucene search index named "agents_master_index" :

```
TemplateFilter={3EA2CB30-0D04-4D73-9282-0103D8F34074} & StartSearchLocation={95A07C68-36B6-4D0D-AAE3-A2BFBF40C2C6}&SortField=Agent Name
```

I have multiple issues:
1) When I open an Item based on this template, it is very slow but it ultimately returns some results on first page of the list, however the pagination and go-to-item buttons are not working and the field is not showing number of pages.

2) If I try template's standard values' item, the above problem doesn't happen but if I click on "next page" button, it returns nothing.
I looked into Search log file to see what's going on. Turns out on when it successfully returns the first page results, it is executing following query:

```
4832 12:32:34 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (agents_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_path:95a07c6836b64d0daae3a2bfbf40c2c6 +_template:3ea2cb300d044d7392820103d8f34074)) - Filter :
```

but to return the second page of results, the multilist runs this query:

```
http://localhost/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx?fromBucketListField=*&sort=Agent%20Name&template={3EA2CB30-0D04-4D73-9282-0103D8F34074}&location=95a07c6836b64d0daae3a2bfbf40c2c6&pageSize=10&pageNumber=2&sc_content=master
```

An returns this JSON-like result which is basically empty:

```
({"CurrentPage":1,"Location":"current item","PageNumbers":0,"SearchCount":"0","SearchTime":"04.3539","facets":null,"items":[],"launchType":"contenteditor:launchtab","ContextData":[],"ContextDataView":[]})
```

and in the search log file what is actually being executed is this:

```
4832 12:28:05 INFO  Search Query : +(_content:* _name:* _displayname:*) +_template:3ea2cb300d044d7392820103d8f34074 +_path:95a07c6836b64d0daae3a2bfbf40c2c6
4832 12:28:05 INFO  Search Index : sitecore_index
4832 12:28:05 INFO  Search Took : 4346ms
```

I don't understand why to retrieve the second page its looking into sitecore_index instead of "agents_master_index". What is wrong here? Should i fix my query? How can I force it to pick the correct lucene index (if this is the reason behind all this confusing problem?

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

By the way, the StartSearchLocation is referring to an items bucket. The "agents_master_index" is referring to same location in its definition.

**UPDATE**

OK, so far I have managed to work around the second problem. After exchanging some comments with Richard, I concluded that (at least in Sitecore 8) content editor expects to find items which we want to search in multilist component in the same index which "Root" item exists ( {11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111} ) so I just added same crawler we had in "agents_master_index" to the "sitecore_index" and it worked!

However, this is still working only on template's standard values item. So the first problem has not been solved yet. In other words, the multilist doesn't work when clicking on second page or do any search on the items which have been created based on that template, it only works properly on the template itself (the standard values item)

I came across this [Fix for Sitecore Multilist and TreeList with Search Bug](https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/bug-sitecore-multilist-and-treelist-with-search-field-search-not-working-intermittently/) which looks very similar to my problem, I tried it but it didn't worked for me :(

Comment: How are you specifying that the Multilist should use the custom search index? Have you removed the `sitecore_master_index`. IIRC the Content Editor controls will use the `sitecore_master_index` for all searches. Do you have some thing custom to change that behavior?

Comment: @RichardSeal  hmmm ! good point! Actually this solution is using sharded index setting. Along with couple of other indexes, there is just a `sitecore_index` (like examples in the default installation) and there isn't any `sitecore_master_index` and I noticed it is not covering entire content tree. Do you mean content editor is supporting `sitecore_master_index` only and not `sitecore_index` in sharded configuration? Or you mean whatever the index is, there must be an index which covers the content tree from top to toe?

Comment: It sounds like you have some very customized index configuration there. OOTB there is not an index called `sitecore_index`. And yes, in Sitecore 8 there should be a top to bottom index for the content editor to use.  I have come across the same issue you are seeing due to the different code paths used to build up the index query.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds like a problem because an index which covers everything would be slow and heavy for crawling and indexing. In this solution there are few item buckets with 3k ~ 5k items in each. One thing that still I don't understand is that why the content search on back end still works very fast with no problem with this sharded configuration, whereas the multilist has this problem. How come the latter is not smart enough to just work like the content search on the bucket itself? Is there anyway to work around this, perhaps specifying the correct index to pick (for multilist) I wonder?